# Message 'Requires authentication' - Github API with Python

Tags: python, github, github-api

I'm trying to use Github API with Python and, so far, I was able to scrap data from public repositories normally.

However, even after I gave all the available permissions to my token, I'm still unable to access my own user data and to create my own repository.

When I try to access my own user, it returns the error `{'message': 'Requires authentication', 'documentation_url': 'https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/users#get-the-authenticated-user'}`, even though I provided the token as one of the parameters

What am I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code. The variable `github_token` is a string with my Github token.

```
import requests
import json

headers = {"Authorization":github_token}

generic_response = requests.get("https://api.github.com/user",headers=headers)

user = generic_response.json()

user
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the [authentication documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/authenticating-to-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28), which provides this example:

```
curl --request GET \
--url "https://api.github.com/octocat" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer YOUR-TOKEN" \
--header "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28"
```

Your authorization header is incorrect. Instead of:

```
headers = {"Authorization":github_token}
```

You need:

```
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {github_token}"}
```